# canvas security error for svg images

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

What I'm trying to do is draw svg image on canvas and then create a PNG image of this canvas.
Here is an example of what I do:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload  = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
                var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
        img.crossorigin = "Anonymous"; //not sure this affects anything...
        img.src="some image url"
```

When I set a source of png/jpeg image it works fine but then the src is of a svg image I get "**Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18**" when calling "**canvas.toDataURL("image/png")**".
I don't understand what's the difference?

The same happens when I take an inline svg and render it inside the canvas and then try to create the png image. I don't have the code right now with me - I'll add it later if necessary.

Comment: Does the SVG reference any external resources? An embedded raster image maybe?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, here is the svg (it is very simple):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in"><circle id="circle1" r="30" cx="34" cy="34" style="fill: red; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2"/>
 </svg>

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Apparently canvas has another function to draw svgs "drawSvg" so I used it and it works.

Comment: Are you sure this function is supported in all browsers and not a browser-specific extension? I can't find that function in the [whatwg specifications of canvas](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html).

Comment: can you please tell me how to use that function?